# How can I add extra data to Alte Beacon

Tags: altbeacon

I was building a beacon with AlteBeacon library, this was created fined but I would like to add extra data but I do not know  how to do that. For example  I would like to register product name and price in my new beacon.

```
public class Tab1Register extends  Fragment {

    private BluetoothAdapter blVer;
    private TextView device;
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1reg, container, false);
        device = rootView.findViewById(R.id.device);
        blVer = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        boolean le2MPhySupported;
        //device.setText("hola");
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            // Call some material design APIs here
            device.setText("supported");
            Beacon beacon = new Beacon.Builder()
                    .setId1("2f234454-cf6d-4a0f-adf2-f4911ba9ffa6")
                    .setId2("1")
                    .setId3("2")
                    .setManufacturer(0x0118)
                    .setTxPower(-59)
                    .setDataFields(Arrays.asList(new Long[] {0l}))
                    .setBluetoothName("Paulo")
                    .build();

            BeaconParser beaconParser = new BeaconParser()
                    .setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25");
            BeaconTransmitter beaconTransmitter = new BeaconTransmitter(getActivity(), beaconParser);

            beaconTransmitter.startAdvertising(beacon);
        } else {
            // Implement this feature without material design
            device.setText("Not supported");
        }

        return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Understand that there is limited data space in a BLE advertisement.  Each beacon format has a different number of data bytes available.  For iBeacon, the number is 0 bytes, for Eddystone-UID, the number is 2 bytes and for AltBeacon, there is one byte.

The code shown in the question already adds this one byte of data to the advertisement, giving it a value of 0.  If you want to change the value to 255, for example, change the code to this:

`.setDataFields(Arrays.asList(new Long[] {255l}))`

Don't let the fact that the data type in the setDataFields method takes an array of Long confuse you.  Because only one byte is available in the single data field for this beacon format, you cannot store an entire long value (which would be 8 bytes) in the data field.  The value must be between 0-255.

Comment: Thank you your support is greatly appreciated, I follow your adviser I will change this values in my code